# Where is directory path to SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't understand where I can find the SQL Server drive. I can't import any file to SQL Server with `BULK INSERT`, I get this error:

> Cannot bulk load. The file "C:\ICO_DB\MSSQLTIPS_XML.xml" does not exist or you don't have file access rights

Why other people insert files with the absolute address?

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is the service account SQL Server is running under doesn't have access to the directory. You either need to place it in a directory it does have access to, give it permissions to the directory, or change the service account to one that does (and also to the existing files).

Comment: The drive is **on the machine** where SQL Server runs - so if this is a **remote** SQL Server - the drive is **that remote machine's `C:\`** drive - not yours locally. ....

Comment: Thank you for reponses. SQL Server is in my C drive in Program Files. Sorry, really I don't understand what I have to exactly do.

Comment: And C Drive has full control permission for user name, which I use for login to SSMS.

Comment: @Karlossos . . . SQL Server runs under a specific user account.  You have to give this account access to other drives so it can see them.

Comment: I run SELECT CURRENT_USER; GO, and server return name 'dbo', but when I want set permission for users in C drive I see only 4 chooses (Auth. Users, SYSTEM, Administrators (DESKTOP-xxxxxx/Administrators and USERS (DESKTOP-xxxxxx/Users). xxxxxxx meaning my user name from SSMS login.

Comment: I found solution: I tried load xml file with address 'C:ICO_DB\MSSQLTIPS_XML.xml' not with 'C:\ICO_DB\MSSQLTIPS_XML.xml'. Thank you for your answers.